# How to redirect to another page in Remix.run?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, remix.run

I was trying to redirect to another page in Remix.run

```js
// app/routes/signup.jsx
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";

export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Signup to SolveIt</h1>
      <button onClick={() => redirect("/login")}>Login</button> // trying to redirect to '/login' route
    </>
  );
}
```

But, I'm getting an error in the console everytime which says :

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , import_node.redirect) is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Remix, redirects are performed on the server inside a `loader` or `action`.

Your example looks like it could be handled by a simple `<Link>`

```js
export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Signup to SolveIt</h1>
      <Link to="/logon">Login</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is how you would do it if you really needed to redirect

```js
// routes/login.tsx

export async function action({ request }: ActionArgs) {
  const formData = await request.formData()
  const username = formData.get("username")
  const password = formData.get("password")

  const isValid = await validateUser(username, password)

  if (isValid) {
    throw redirect('/') // valid login so redirect to home page
  }
  return json({ formError: 'Invalid username or password' })
}

export default function Login() {
  const data = useActionData<typeof action>()
  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
      <button>Login</button>
      { data?.formError && <p>{data?.formError}</p> }
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Here we post the username and password to the `action` function. We get the form data from the request. We can then verify if the credentials are valid. If so, we `throw redirect('/')`. The redirect function returns a Response with the correct status and headers.

If it is invalid, we return an error message to the user with the `json` function. Note how we used `throw` instead of return for the redirect. This is so we can use type inference in the call to `useActionData<typeof action>()`. Remix will infer the return value from the payload of `json` and `defer` functions.

In the UI component, we check for the error with `useActionData()`. Since it only returns a value after an action call (POST), it can also be `undefined`. We check if `data?.formError` has a value and if so render it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the methods in Kiliman's answer, there is also the the [`useNavigate`](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-navigate#usenavigate) hook. Which can also be used for page navigation on the client side.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

export default function Signup() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Signup to SolveIt</h1>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/login")}>Login</button> // trying to redirect to '/login' route
    </>
  );
}
```